# I can't run Eclipse from the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, eclipse, terminal.app

I have an installed copy of Eclipse Oxygen installed on my MacBook running macOS 10.13.4 using the Oomph installer. I am trying to write a shell script that uses the Eclipse command line tools. (I have seen the `eclipse` command documented in many places, including on the Eclipse Foundation's website.)

However, when running `$ eclipse` in my terminal, it can't find the command.

How do I install/where do I find the `eclipse` command?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is installed as a macOS App so you need to use the `open` command to run it from a shell script. Something like:

```
open -n /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

Comment: Hm... the file /Applications/Eclipse.app does not extant. So where is my eclipse installed?

Comment: Possibly Oomph puts things somewher elese - I don't use it so can't say.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the executable file under

```
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
```